# Consul - "No private IPv4 address found" error

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, configuration

"ubuntu 20.04"

I am trying to start Consul service with this command:

```
/usr/bin/consul agent -server -ui -data-dir=/temp/consul -bootstrap-expect=1 -node=vault -bind=0.0.0.0 -config-dir=/etc/consul.d/
```

It gives ==> “No private IPv4 address found”

I also found a page regarding same issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/725) but since I am newbie at linux.

I followed [this page](https://github.com/b1tsized/vault-tutorial/tree/main/01-getting-started) to install it.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

The`-bind` with `0.0.0.0` is not a routable address so it will default to the local interfaces `127.0.0.1` and other network interfaces available, but in your case looks like non of the network interfaces expose a private IP (like docker and stuff).

So if you don't have a private IP, just use `[-advertise][1]` (in `consul.hcl` it's called `advertise_addr`) with your Public IP.

```bsh
sudo -u consul /usr/bin/consul agent -server -ui -data-dir=/opt/consul -bootstrap-expect=1 -node=vault -bind=0.0.0.0 -advertise=IP.Pub.add.ress -config-dir=/etc/consul.d/
```